# Unable to stretch HTML footer to the full width

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I made a HTML email layout using table, the design is working fine in my machine but when I put the code to test in **putsmail** the footer moves to the left when I view the mail in the dekstop.
It should come like this:
[image]

Its coming like this:
[image]

My HTML code:

```
<!--Footer-->
                  <table class="footer">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding: 50px;background-color: #f7f7f7">
                        <table width="100%">
                          <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.5;">
                            Having Trouble with something?
                            <br>
                            Reach out to us <a href="#">support@vantagecircle.com</a>
                            </p>
                            <img style="display: block; margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto; padding-bottom: 25px;" src="https://i.ibb.co/1Z05xTH/vc-footer-logo.png" width="120px" />
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

My CSS code:

```
.footer{
        align-content: center;
        width: max-content;
        position: relative;
      }
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s safer to use inline CSS for email templates, I also don’t think any email clients supports the `align-content` property or even `max-content` on `width`. Maybe try it like this:

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr width="100%">
    <td style="padding: 50px;background-color:#f7f7f7">
      <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.5;">
          Having Trouble with something?
          <br>
          Reach out to us <a href="#">support@vantagecircle.com</a>
        </p>
        <img style="display: block; margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto; padding-bottom: 25px;" src="https://i.ibb.co/1Z05xTH/vc-footer-logo.png" width="120px" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I'm using `width` inline there, and added a `div` in the inner `td` to align to the center.

Answer (score 0):

Use `width: 100%` for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width: max-content;` to `width: 100%;` and it should work.
You can read more about how "max-content" works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content)